# flutter sign app with cert.dar playConsole

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, apk

I have an app in the playstore created with kodular (similar to appinventor),

I started over with flutter and I like the result

However, when I try to deploy on the playstore, the app is refused with a reason: `Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key`.

Do I have the upload_cert.der file, and how can I sign the flutter app with that certificate?

(i use android studio)

Answer (score 0):

Your Apps key should match otherwise you will not able to update the apps. You can find the keystore in kodular